# Print theme logo path in my twig file

Tags: theming, 8

In `mytheme.theme` file I have:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      $variables['logopath'] = '/' . drupal_get_path('theme','mytheme') . '/logo.png';
}
```

In my `menu--main.html.twig` I have:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ logopath }}" />
```

But it's not printing my logo? The src is still empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use different theme hooks `page` and `menu`.

If you want to use the variable in

```
menu--main.html.twig
```

use

```
function mytheme_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
```